# Jenkins CLI won't install; it just hangs

Tags: java, jenkins, command-line-interface, rhel

I think this is the right place for Jenkins CLI questions.
I installed Jenkins on RHEL v 7.  I now want to try out the CLI.

From the command prompt, I ran this:

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://x.x.x.x:8080/ help

When I am root, it just hangs.  When I am a user that has permissions to install packages, I get prompted for a password for the it private SSH key (id_rsa).  I enter it, then it just hangs.

The command I am running was lifted from my Jenkins installation.  If you log into the GUI of Jenkins, then go to Manage Jenkins -> Jenkins CLI, there is a command that purports to download jenkins-cli.jar and install it.  All I want to do is run it successfully.  Why is it just hanging?

Comment: Are you on windows , mac, or linux? Do you have security enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the command on the machine with jenkins installed?

If so, could you try

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ help
```

or

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ help
```

What's the error output?

Comment: there is no output, it hangs.